# How to change sbt-docker settings to choose an specific route for artifacts

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-docker

Right now, whenever I execute the `sbt docker` command of the [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) plugin within my project, it generates the artifacts (dockerfile and jars) under the `[app-route]/target/docker/` folder.

Is there a way to change that "default" route, so It can generate the artifacts elsewhere? Let's say, in `[app-route]/docker` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the staging directory by setting target in docker, for example target in docker := "docker".

Thanks to the creator of the [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) plugin that answered the question [here](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker/issues/34).